# Files created in docker build not present in container created from image

Tags: wordpress, docker, gulp

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress

#make sure necessary tools for publishing are installed
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs git && \
    npm install -g npm gulp bower

ADD . /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name

RUN cd /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme-name \
    && npm install \
    && npm run build \
    && rm -rf node_modules \
    && rm -rf bower_components \
    && find ./* -type f -printf "%h%f\n" | sort \
    && cd /

VOLUME ["/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ca-ticket.com"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

When I build it, the second RUN command produces several files that get dropped into the `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ca-ticket.com/dist` folder, and when I view the build log I can see clearly that the files are getting created (that is why the `find ./* -type f -printf "%h%f\n" | sort` is there.

From the log:

```
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/scriptsjquery.js
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/scriptsjquery.js.map
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/scriptsmain.js
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/scriptsmain.js.map
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/stylesmain.css
build   11-Apr-2016 18:51:01    ./dist/stylesmain.css.map
```

... and so on.

However, when I create a container from this image, the `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/ca-ticket.com/dist` simply doesn't exist!

I'm suspect I must be doing something silly to cause docker to ignore a layer, but I'm not sure what is wrong about this process.

**edit:**
The build command is:

```
docker build --force-rm=true --tag="<tag here>" /path/to/context
```

I've also tried with the `--no-cache` option with no change to the result.

I'm running the image with:

```
docker run --name <name> -d -p 81:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=<dbhost> -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=<dbuser> -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=<pass> -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=<dbname> -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=<tblprefix> <imagename>
```

Comment: Could you provide the build and run command please?

Comment: @Auzias I've updated the question with the build and run commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Turned out the base wordpress imags exposed a volume /var/www/html that it then copied the wordpress install to in the entrypoint.sh script.

In the end, I moved the app to /theme-dir and ran the build in that folder, and updated the entrypoint.sh script to add a symlink from the wordpress themes directory to my folder.